# How do you author a module that is compatible with CommonJS, AMD and Browser in ES6 with Babel?

Tags: javascript, browser, ecmascript-6, amd, commonjs

In normal ES5 if I want to author a package that could be use on either server side (via CJS, AMD, RequireJS) or browser, I would do something like this:

```
(function(name, definition)){
   if (typeof exports !== 'undefined' && typeof module !== 'undefined') {
       module.exports = definition();
   } else if (typeof define === 'function' && typeof define.amd === 'object') {
       define(definition);
   } else {
       this[name] = definition();
   }
}('foo', function foo(){
       'use strict';

        return 'foo';
})
```

How'd I achieve this functionality while writing a package in ES6?

What I tried:

```
if (typeof exports !== 'undefined' && typeof module !== 'undefined') export Foo;
else if (typeof define === 'function' && typeof define.amd === 'object') define(Foo);
else this['Foo'] = Foo;
```

While transpiling this, Babel throws me an error:

```
SyntaxError: src/index.js: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level (10:69)
   9 |
> 10 | if (typeof exports !== 'undefined' && typeof module !== 'undefined') export Foo;
     |                                                                      ^
  11 | else if (typeof define === 'function' && typeof define.amd === 'object') define(Foo);
  12 | else this['Foo'] = Foo;
  13 |
```

It did work when I used `module.exports` instead of `export` but is it possible to do this strictly using ES6?

Comment: This is also called UMD, *Universal Module Definition*. Might help your search a bit :-)

Comment: You should not need to write this code yourself. You should just put the ES6 `export` declaration in your source. The UMD should be generated by the transpiler from it.

Comment: https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/modules/ ... it's all in the docs.

Comment: @Bergi, it did. Totally helped me find what I was looking for. Turned out I just have to run this: `babel --modules umd ...`

Comment: @FelixKling, Thanks a lot. I didn't thought babel would provide such thing out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there is no real way to include ES6 modules in a universal module definition because ES6 modules are strictly one per file and all import and export statements must be at the top level.

When the loader spec is done there will likely be a way to add a module into the registry and that will be how you'd include ES6 modules in a UMD, until then, since no browsers actually support ES6 modules your only targets are AMD and CommonJS,  but you should be using one of the many compilers or trsnspilers like browserify or Babel to do that for you.

Comment: what do you mean by "all import and export statements must be at the top level", I got this error for my application, but did not understand it, I've a file named main.js, and the first 2 lines in it are the import statements, so what is the "top level" required!

Comment: import and export statements can't be inside function bodies,  loops or if/else blocks.

ok

`import foo from 'bar';`

not ok

`if (something) {
   import foo from 'bar';
} else {
   import foo from 'baz';
}

Answer (score 0):

You won't have one universal output but [StealJS](http://stealjs.com/) can export your Babel transpiled ES6 project to CommonJS, AMD and as a standalone. For CommonJS and AMD your original module structure is being kept so you are able to still load only the dependencies you really need.

The [project exporting](http://stealjs.com/docs/StealJS.project-exporting.html) guide explains it in a little more detail but when using the NPM workflow this is how your build script looks like (it will also build CSS/LESS/SASS and other dependencies if included):

```
{
    dist: {
        system: {
            config: "package.json!npm"
        },
        outputs: {
            "+cjs": {},
            "+amd": {},
            "+global-js": {},
            "+global-css": {}
        }
    }
}
```